# Using custom map with Turtlebot3 for gmapping

Tags: slam, ros-noetic, turtlebot3, turtlebot-gazebo, turtlebot-navigation

I am using ROS noetic . I am trying to map a custom gazebo world using turtlebot3. I have used the cafe world :

https://github.com/SyllogismRXS/syllo-gazebo/blob/master/catkin_ws/src/eye_gazebo/worlds/cafe.world

I downloaded this world and added the world file location in the launch file.

Then i tried following the tutorial from turtlebot3 for mapping :
https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/slam_simulation/

### the issue  I am facing is that when I use the gazebo world provided by turtlebot it shows no error whatsoever.  when I try to do gmapping on the custom map it shows an error :

```
[ WARN] [1704371582.895113558]: MessageFilter [target=odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.gmapping.message_filter] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
[ WARN] [1704371582.897833063]: MessageFilter [target=odom ]:   The majority of dropped messages were due to messages growing older than the TF cache time.  The last message's timestamp was: 149.451000, and the last frame_id was: base_
```

### screenshots and launch file to reproduce the error:

following is rviz :

[image]

here is the terminal screen shot :

[image]

and here are the launch files :

````
<launch>
  <arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>
  <arg name="x_pos" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="y_pos" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="z_pos" default="0.0"/>

  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find turtlebot_gazebo)/worlds/cafe.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="0.1"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
  </include>  


  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

  <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -model turtlebot3_burger -x $(arg x_pos) -y $(arg y_pos) -z $(arg z_pos) -param robot_description" />

</launch>
```
````

Comment: Please paste console output as text, not as a screenshot. Images are not text searchable.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working in simulation, you should set `use_sim_time` to `true`:

```xml
<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find turtlebot_gazebo)/worlds/cafe.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true" />
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
</include>
```